# Find the polygon according to the relation given below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

If A, B, C and D are four consecutive vertices of a regular polygon we have to $\frac{1}{AB} = \frac{1}{AC}+\frac{1}{AD}$ .  How many sides does the polygon have?

Solution by trigonometry..
$AB=2rsen(x)\\ AC=2rsen(2x)\\ AD=2rsen(3x)\\ \therefore \frac{1}{sen(x)}=\frac{1}{sen2x}+\frac{1}{sen3x}\implies \frac{1}{sen(x)}-\frac{1}{sen2x}=\frac{1}{sen3x}\\ \\sen(2x)=2sen(x)cos(x):\frac{2cos(x)-1}{sen(2x)}=\frac{1}{sen(3x)}\\ \therefore 2sen(3x)cos(x)-sen(3x)=sen(2x)\\ sen(A)cos(B)=\frac{{}sen(A+B)+sen(A-B)}{2}:\\ sen(4x)+sen(2x)-sen(3x)=sen(2x) \implies sen(4x)=sen(3x)\\ \therefore 4x+3x=180^o. \implies \boxed{x=\frac{180^o}{7}}.$

[image]
(Solução:LuizFuentes)

Would it be possible to solve by geometry?

Comment: If $HA$ is a straight line, then you can easily infer that $x=\frac{180}{7}$. With this in mind, you can count the sides/vertices you see currently and reflect them along $HA$ to complete the polygon, that will give you its complete shape

Comment: @Goku Thank you, but as a relation was provided, I would like to know if there is any geometric manipulation to determine that the polygon is a heptagon. Due to the symmetry of the design it is simple to understand but it would need development to arrive at the solution as was done with trigonometry

Comment: You can easily solve this via complex numbers too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $AB=x, AC=y$ and $AD=z$.

In the figure, $H$ is a point on $BD$ such that $DH=x$

Thus $\angle DHC= \frac{180^o-\alpha}{2}=90^o-\frac{\alpha}{2}$

$$\angle BHC=180^o-\left( 90^o-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)=90^o+\frac{\alpha}{2} \tag{1}$$

Also $$\angle ABD=180^o-3 \alpha   \tag{2}$$

Noting that $BD=AC=y \implies$  $$HB=y-x \tag{3}$$

From the given  $$\frac{1}{AB}=\frac{1}{AC}+\frac{1}{AD}$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{z}$$

$$\implies \frac{y-x}{xy}=\frac{1}{z}$$

$$\implies \frac{y-x}{x}=\frac{y}{z}$$

$$\implies \frac{HB}{BC}=\frac{BD}{DA}$$

$$\because  \angle BGA= \angle HBC = \alpha$$

$$\therefore  \Delta DBA \sim \Delta BHC$$

Hence $$\angle DBA = \angle BHC \tag{4}$$

Put $(1), (2)$ into $(4)$

$$180^0-3 \alpha= 90^0+\frac{\alpha}{2}$$

$$\alpha = \frac{180^o}{7} $$

Answer (score 4):

$\square ABCD$ is an isosceles trapezoid. Let its diagonals meet at $X$, forming isosceles $\triangle XAD$, and let $\overline{CD'}$ create rhombus $\square ABCD'$ and isosceles $\triangle CDD'$.

[image]

As inscribed angles of the regular polygon's circumcircle subtending congruent chords, we have
$$\angle CBD = \angle BCA = \angle BDC = \angle BDA \quad =: \theta$$
We readily conclude that $\angle CXD = \angle CD'D = 2\theta$, so that $\square XCDD'$ is cyclic. This, in turn, implies that $\angle XD'C$ (marked with a dot in the figure) also has measure $\theta$. Moreover, calculating in two ways the [power of point $A$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) relative to that quadrilateral's circumcircle, we have
$$|AD'||AD|=|AX||AC| \tag1$$

Note that the above holds for any regular polygon. (Indeed, to help convey this universality, the figure is based on the $9$-gon instead of the target $7$-gon.) Now, we'll invoke the exercise's given relation, and manipulate it a bit in light of $\square ABCD'$ being a rhombus:
$$\begin{align}
\frac1{|AB|} = \frac1{|AC|}+\frac1{|AD|} &\qquad\to\qquad (\,|AD|-|AB|\,)|AC| = |AB||AD| \tag2 \\
&\qquad\to\qquad |D'D||AC| = |AD'||AD| \overset{(1)}{=} |AX||AC| \tag3 \\[8pt]
&\qquad\to\qquad |D'D| = |AX| = |XD| \tag4
\end{align}$$
Therefore, $\triangle DXD'$ is isosceles (which doesn't *look* true above, indicating that we've broken universality) and has angle sum $180^\circ=\theta+3\theta+3\theta=7\theta$. We conclude that $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are vertices of a regular $7$-gon. $\square$